# XSLT Help : Copy elements <choose>

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

With my limited knowledge of XSL programming I have come up with this code:

(Post updated: XSLT is now working - Updated for the benefit of others if at all!)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction"
xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" 
exclude-result-prefixes="env">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/nm:Responses">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/Envelope">
    <nm:Responses xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
        <BTEMessages/>
        <SystemContext/>
                <Error>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Body"/>
               </Error>
    </nm:Responses>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The purpose of the is to process the file (at the end of the post) and get the result below:

***Required result for 'Error' file :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nm:Response xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
   <BTEMessages/>
   <SystemContext/>
   <Error>
      <Body>
         <Response status="1">
            <Description>DESC</Description>
            <Errors>
               <Error>500</Error>
            </Errors>
         </Response>
      </Body>
   </Error>
</nm:Response>
```

***Required result for 'Response' file:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nm:Response xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
   <BTEMessages>
      <InOrderContext xmlns:n0="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
         <SendTimestamp>01-06-2017:0506230000</SendTimestamp>
      </InOrderContext>
      <SystemContext>
         <Client>FDP</Client>
         <CorrelationId>34553FTG25543SFD134</CorrelationId>
         <BusinessContext>RECONCL</BusinessContext>
      </SystemContext>
   </BTEMessages>
</nm:Response>
```

***File 1: Error ***

```
<Envelope >
    <Body>
      <Response status="1">
        <Description>DESC</Description>
        <Errors>
          <Error>500</Error>
        </Errors>
      </Response>
    </Body>
  </Envelope>
```

***File 2: Response:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nm:Response xmlns:nm="http://fsag.de/BusinessTransaction">
<BTEMessage>
  <InOrderContext>
     <SendTimestamp>01-06-2017:0506230000</SendTimestamp>
  </InOrderContext>
  <SystemContext>
    <Client>FDP</Client>
    <CorrelationId>34553FTG25543SFD134</CorrelationId>
    <BusinessContext>RECONCL</BusinessContext>
  </SystemContext>
</BTEMessage>
</nm:Response >
```

When i try to run the XSL is failing. Please any help here?

Comment: You need to spend an hour learning the basics of XSLT  before you ask here. And please stop asking the same question again and again (this is your third time, I believe).

Comment: I'm trying here to get this done. As I said earlier I have no experience working on xslt and its on job spec which I'm trying to solve it and that's what forums are here to help people. I'm not asking help without putting any effort here. It's a genuine request to guide on how to approach.

Comment: If you don't know that you must have a template at the top level of your stylesheet (and don't have a testing tool that would tel you this when you don't), then you have no business asking here. Not to mention that you have been given a working example, and you can't even adapt that.

Comment: Well you got to read well and clear, I cant write down a disclaimer each time to make you understand that my level of xsl programming is as good as urs. For for your information, I'm using http://xslttest.appspot.com/ for testing the xsl. Doesn't it sound good enough for starters????.....and my apology for not updating the xsl I'm using now with the start template which I had been using prior ur much helpful and inspiring update !!! thanks

Comment: @Prabhu, I agree with michael. This is no way to learn a new programming language. We're here to help you when you get stuck, not to provide a personalized one-to-one training course. Find a good book on XSLT, read it,   run some of the examples, and then come back here.

Comment: @Michael, I would definitely agree to your point. This is not a one-one training. If I had to provide some forum help on SAP/SALESFORCE I wuld advise the same as you suggested but if i can see one had put effort (atleast a basic minimum) I would go further by to help and that's what I have done now...reading one XSL docs and now able to write a bare minimum code and I think I'm close to get it done but not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @PrabhuSethupathy, you are operating under a misconception.  SO is **not** here to help you.  Helping you, when that happens, is a happy side effect of what we do here, which is to *build a knowledge base* by answering good, novel questions that fall within our scope.  It does not serve our purpose to field poor questions or to field substantially the same question multiple times. You should furthermore understand that there is a *quid pro quo* involved: in exchange for answering your questions, we request that you in fact make them good and novel ones.

Comment: @John.....perhaps you may be right. My post/question may not be of a high standard like what you all expect but I don't think that it is of quite less standard when compare to similar questions asked in this forum. When you try to reply/provide answers to forum question there is an element of help been offered and said that I am not expecting people to provide training via forum questions.  I think I had given enough justification on my post and why I had to ask which some feels silly considering their expertise. I would like to keep the questions neat and meaningful for the benefit of others

Answer (score 0):

XSL updated with working version.